# shinyjqui orderinput button size [CSS]

Tags: css, r, shiny

I'm using `class = "btn-group-vertical",` to align my `orderInput`s vertically, and I want the drop zone to also be vertically aligned next to it. I tried using fluidRows and column sizes of 6 to have the two divs next to one another

But the current output looks like this:

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)

ui <- fluidPage(


  sidebarPanel(
    fluidRow(
      selectInput("RECIPE", "",
                  c("A1" = "A",
                    "C2 & D3" = "CD",
                    "None" = "none"),
                  selected = "none")
    ),

    fluidRow(
      column(6, div(id = "row_container",
                 style = "min-height: 500px;
                 margin-top: 0.5em; margin-left:-1em;
                 border-style: dotted;
                 border-color: #A9A9A9;
                 border-width: 2px;", uiOutput('row'))),
      column(6, div(id = "row_container",
                    style = "min-height: 500px;
                    margin-top: 0.5em; margin-left:-1em;
                    border-style: dotted;
                    border-color: #A9A9A9;
                    border-width: 2px;", uiOutput('row_output')))
    )
  ),

  mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput('order'))

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$order <- renderPrint({ 
    print(input$row_dest_order) 
  })


  # Create shinyjqui output, and re-trigger when action button is clicked
  output$row <- renderUI({
    switch(
      input$RECIPE,
      A = orderInput('row_source', 'Row', class = "btn-group-vertical", items = c("B", "C", "D"), connect = 'row_dest'),
      CD = orderInput('row_source', 'Row',  class = "btn-group-vertical", items = c("A", "B"), connect = 'row_dest'),
      orderInput('row_source', 'Row',  class = "btn-group-vertical", items = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), connect = 'row_dest')
    )
  })

  output$row_output <- renderUI({
    switch(
      input$RECIPE,
      A = orderInput('row_dest', '', items = c("A"), connect = 'row_source', class = "btn-group-vertical"),
      CD = orderInput('row_dest', '', items = c("C", "D"), connect = 'row_source', class = "btn-group-vertical"),
      orderInput('row_dest', '', items = NULL, connect = 'row_source', class = "btn-group-vertical")
    )
  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I tried adding custom css to #btn, #btn-class-vertical, and some other classes that I found when exploring the inspection tool but I still haven't quite gotten it right.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `width = "100%"` to all the`orderInput`:

```
orderInput('row_source', 'Row', class = "btn-group-vertical", 
                     items = c("B", "C", "D"), connect = 'row_dest', 
                     width = "100%")
```

Unrelated but do not use twice the same `id` (`row_container`).